# Summing the total of the selected column in PHP, is my code right?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a code for this total sales of "Price" column, am i doing it right???

```
public function gettotalsales()
{
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("Select SUM(Price) From tbl_orderlist where Price != '' ");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
}
```

[Database img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z0Ba.png)

Comment: Test it and you will come to know if you are right or wrong.

Comment: looks good, execute it and see whats happen?? Update `SUM(Price)` to `SUM(Price) sum`

Comment: update :     where Price != 'Pending'

Comment: From where `Pending` comes into picture @Diksha ?

Comment: There is 'Pending' in column of Price

Comment: How you know @Diksha ? I am not able to see any where `Pending` word is used in question.

Comment: oh yah uhm i removed the pending parts i was told that they were not necessary.. http://pastebin.com/gHmCJ4P2  < currently using this code and still not showing up the results of the sum

Comment: Run your query in PHPMYADMIN

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the below line only

```
Select SUM(Price) From tbl_orderlist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SUM(Price) From tbl_orderlist
```

Comment: http://s11.postimg.org/y5lvlgkz7/image.png  tried your code,  still not showin up 
public function gettotalsales()
{
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("Select SUM(Price) From tbl_orderlist");
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt;